# Cocoa get textfield and get text from it

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

I'm brand new to cocoa and objective c, I'm using xcode and trying to set up a basic interface with two textfields and a button and when the button is clicked I get the data input into the textfields. How do I get ahold of the textfields so i can get the text from them?

Comment: What documentation have you read and what about it didn't make sense?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would benefit from reading the cocoa tutorials on apple's website.

All you need to do is open your nib file and click the show assistant editor.  Ctrl click the text field and drag it to the header file in the right window.  Name the property and leave it as an outlet.  This will create a property that you can use to access the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You should link textField with property in you view, then you can call textField.text for getting text

Comment: how, I haven't been able to find out how to do that